# How To String Format Complex Json Body in C#

Tags: c#, json

i have the following code

```
var UUID = "ExampleX";
var NumID = "ExampleY";
var Payload = string.Format("{\"API1\":{\"API2\":\"API3\",\"API4\":5},\"API6\":\"{0}\",\"API7\":\"{1}\",\"API8\":\"API8\"}",UUID,NumID);
```

i'm trying to replace the input for {0} and {1} with UUID and NumID but i kept getting the following Error

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

i'm still learning how to code any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could [parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) the Json String as `JObject` and then replace the API6 and API7 values. For example,

```
var json = "{\"API1\":{\"API2\":\"API3\",\"API4\":5},\"API6\":\"{0}\",\"API7\":\"{1}\",\"API8\":\"API8\"}";
var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
jo["API6"] = UUID;
jo["API7"] = NumID;
var Payload = jo.ToString();
```

Output

```
{
  "API1": {
    "API2": "API3",
    "API4": 5
  },
  "API6": "ExampleX",
  "API7": "ExampleY",
  "API8": "API8"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the json brackets with double brackets so they are not interpreted as a placeholder:

```
var Payload = string.Format("{{\"API1\":{{\"API2\":\"API3\",\"API4\":5}},\"API6\":\"{0}\",\"API7\":\"{1}\",\"API8\":\"API8\"}}",UUID,NumID);
```